# Apostrophe error when using MySQL on Centos7

Tags: php, mysql, roundcube

I am trying to install roundcube. Anyways, this is what I need to enter.

```
> CREATE DATABASE roundcubemail CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
> CREATE USER roundcube@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; (THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS)
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON roundcubemail.* TO roundcube@localhost;
```

When I try to enter `''` I end up getting `‘ ’` which causes a syntax error.

I am on a minimal install. I am using PHP.

I'm a beginner, so take it easy on me if I am missing an obvious step haha.

Comment: What is "_..the apostrophe that MySQL accepts.._"? What is the Error? What exactly is the code?

Comment: The code is in the opening post. What I mean is that when I try put the password in ' ' this type of apostrophe pops up: ’ which then causes a syntax error.

Comment: and what about this : `CREATE USER 'roundcube'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: What program are you typing these commands into? Are you typing them or copy / pasting from somewhere else?

Comment: Often times I see `' '` changes to `‘ ’` in Microsoft Words.

Comment: @Phil I am using a CentOS7 machine with a minimal install. I am typing these commands in myself.

Comment: @GNassro The command itself is fine, but its the ```' '``` that are causing the problems. When I type into the command line, they end up looking like ```‘ ’``` instead of ```' '``` which causes a syntax error.

Comment: @SeeNTower we're going to need more details. What application are you typing into? Is it the terminal or something else? How do the apostrophe characters _"end up"_ turning into curly quotes? Do you literally type `'` and what appears on screen is `‘` or does it happen later somehow? Explain the problem in detail with the steps you take. Could you take a screen recording at all (eg, using [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek))